# Force triggering onChange of select dropdown

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a form with steps created with GravitForms/WordPress.

I created a function to copy dropdown value to an input value and a div from the first page to the second page.
At the first time, it works fine, but if if go back from page 2 to page 1 et change the select value, the input value doesn't update.

Is there any way to force triggering onChange of select dropdown ?

My code :

```
var select_dates = document.getElementById("input_4_3");
select_dates.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("date_left").innerHTML = select_dates.value;
    document.getElementById("input_4_33").value = select_dates.value;
    console.log(select_dates.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged jQuery so here is a jQuery answer

Change the dropdown and then click the link

You possibly load the selects using AJAX so try this delegation

ctrl-left arrow to come back

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "#input_4_3", function() {
    $("#date_left").html(this.value)
    $("#input_4_33").val(this.value)
    console.log(this.value);
  }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="input_4_3">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="D 1">Date 1</option>
  <option value="D 2">Date 2</option>
</select>
<span id="date_left"></span>
<input type="text" id="input_4_33" />
<a href="https://placeholder.com">Go somewhere</a>
```

Comment: Same problem, i don't know why the fonction doesn't trigger if i go back to the first page.

Comment: Add my code to the end of the page in a script tag

Comment: I did that exactly

Comment: I tried that but no luck. Here is a link (click "Préinscription" buttom to open the form modal) : [link](https://preprod.consiliom.design/produit/les-fondamentaux-du-designer-pour-ameliorer-votre-performance-et-votre-reussite/).  https://ibb.co/ysp7qk2

Comment: probably need to wrap the function in `$(window).on('ajaxComplete', function()`  etc.

Comment: Same :/ https://jsfiddle.net/infinityweb/smfb9to6/4/

Comment: Last chance. Delegate from document

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger change event on select element using this:

```
$('#input_4_3').trigger('change');
```